# Retrieving table field using web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I am new to web2py. 
I have a table(form) and within my python script I want to use specific field values.

```
  def GetData()
       return request.vars.values()
```

This function gives me all the fields together but I want to know how to get a value of 'input1' (for example) field from my form.

form:

```
 <form action="GetData" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formId" method="post" 
 name="formId"> 
     <table>
        <tr id="field1">
          <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text" value="" />
        </tr>

        <tr id="field2">  
          <input id="input2" name="input2" type="text" value="" />
        </tr>

        <tr id="field3">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
         </tr>
     </table>
  </form>
```

Thankssss!!!

Comment: request.vars["your_field"]

Answer (score 1):

From the web2py [book](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#request)

> The request object is an instance of the ubiquitous web2py class that is called gluon.storage.Storage, which extends the Python dict class. It is basically a dictionary, but the item values can also be accessed as attributes:

This is what you need.

```
p = request.vars['p'] 
q = request.vars['q']
```

Comment: Got it. thank you so much. the problem was that i was using id instead of name tag. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
input1 = request.vars.input1
etc.
```